# Make window width of screen

Tags: android, html, ios, css, meta

I am making a mobile web page and struggling through dealing with various screen sizes and basically I want to make my page the width of the actual screen not the browser.

Because of the way mobile browsers work, the default "width" of most browsers is 320 pixels when the following meta tag is set:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
```

What can I do to make it so that the page is the full resolution of the screen and not the "resolution" of the browser?

There must be some simple solution..

Note: setting the initial-scale flag to 2 made the page smaller than 320 pixels on both my iphone and android phone (640 and 480 pixels wide respectively) and setting it to .5 made the page 640px wide on both devices, but zoomed in on the android device. It gave the desired effect on the iphone..

My page: [mmhudson.com/index1.html](http://mmhudson.com/index1.html)

Comment: Does adding `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` to the content list help?

Comment: @cimmanon your solution worked. please provide and answer and i will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you're missing from that list is `target-densitydpi=device-dpi`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

> By default, WebView scales a web page so that it is drawn at a size
>   that matches the default appearance on a medium density screen. So, it
>   applies 1.5x scaling on a high density screen (because its pixels are
>   smaller) and 0.75x scaling on a low density screen (because its pixels
>   are bigger).

And

> device-dpi - Use the device's native dpi as the target dpi. Default
>   scaling never occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding maximum-scale and adding densitydpi something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

Here is where you can find good examples for mobile browsers :

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
```

But maybe it depends of the browser.